# Javascript: How compare strings on alphabetical characters only?

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I'm currently rewriting the userlist implementation in an IM client interface that uses JavaScript. The names in this list are currently sorted alphabetically, and I want to edit this so that it only takes alphabetical characters in account when comparing strings.

For instance: "1foo" comes *after* "bar", because "foo" comes after "bar".

I know I could just create two temporary strings by removing all non-alphabetical characters from the two original strings, but I'm guessing that there must be easier ways to do this.

Comment: Can you post the code you're currently using to sort?

Comment: Do you want the strings starting with numbers sorted before or after strings with letters? What do you want to happen?

Comment: You can use custom sort functions in javascript: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml

Comment: I'd just use a regex to get only alphabetic chars and compare those.  I believe that there are some callback versions of the string find functions that could be used too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you have an array of strings called `arr`, you can use this one-liner:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a.replace(/[^a-z]/ig,'') > b.replace(/[^a-z]/ig,'') ? 1 : -1;});
```

`arr` is now sorted taking only letters into account.

Comment: Just a note that if the array is a large array, this sort could be really, really slow because two regular expression replace operations resulting in temporary creation of strings would occur on every comparison in the sort algorithm.